# python add multiple columns to excel file one by one

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have an excel file with multiple sheet, I want to group the columns in the logs list and store them in another excel file, but some sheets do not contain some columns, so tf a column does not exist in a sheet don't store it, the code work well but it store only the last column

```
import pandas as pd
sheets_names = ['R9_14062021','R9_02122020','R9_14062021','R9_28052021','R9_17052021','R9_03052021','R9_14042021','R9_24032020','R9_19032020','R9 30112020','R9_17112020','R7_27012021','LOGS R9 01032021','LOGS R7 SAT01032021','R7_30032020','G9_06032020','G5T_20012021','TNT_08122020','R7_SAT_24112020','G6T_12112020','R9 12102020']

logs = [' Msd','Provider Id','Terminal Type','chgtCh','accessRecordModule','playerPlay startOver','playerPlay PdL','playerPlay PVR','contentHasAds','pdlComplete','lirePdl','lireVod']

dfs_list = pd.read_excel('COMPIL LOGS INDICATEURS V14062021.xlsx',sheet_name = sheets_names )
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_multiple.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
    for sheet in dfs_list:
        df = dfs_list[sheet]
        df['Dt'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Dt']).dt.date
        df1 = df.groupby(['Dt','webApp','mw'])[' Msd'].count()
        for log in logs:
            if log in df:
                df1 = df.groupby(['Dt','webApp','mw'])[log].sum()
                df1.to_update.get(sheet)
    #df1.reset_index(inplace=True)
    df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet)

writer.save()
```

result:
[image]

Comment: What is `df1.to_update`?

Comment: I think to add columns one by one to the dataframe

Comment: DataFrame object does not have a `to_update` method. You need to post the actual output that you're getting when you run this code, and also please include the full stack trace if you get an error.

Comment: I added a picture of the result, if you saw the picture there is only one column, to be specific it's the last one from the logs list, what i want is to add the whole columns form the logs list, and by the way the code work without error

Comment: Please don't post pictures, have a look at this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for an explanation. When I asked for output, I was referring to the output from your python code when you run it in a terminal.

Comment: Note: df1.to_update give an error so i deleted this line and run the code, here is the ouput:  Dt                webApp                     mw       lireVod
         2020-11-26  1.72.10-G5-TEST  2.69.1.35      0
         2020-11-28  1.72.10-G5-TEST  2.72.1.1        2
         2020-12-01  1.72.10-G5            2.59.1.22      3
         2020-12-07  1.72.10-G5-TEST  2.72.1.1      38
         2020-12-08  1.72.10-G5-TEST  2.72.1.1      79